# il gratte les poto

Tags: sens, argot

Que signifie "il gratte les poto" dans [cette chanson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5bpYqj657M) ?

> Il a pas de sous au quartier **il gratte les poto**
>   [...]
>   C'est le genre de gars tout sur lui et **rien dans le frigo**
>   [...]
>   Passes au quartier tu le verras posé sur un banc
>   **Il tient les murs** et avec toi il fait le mec qui n'a pas le temps
>   [...]
>   Tu dois le boycotté

Apparemment "il":

- n'a pas d'argent
- passe son temps à ne rien faire, si j'ai bien [compris](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pilier_de_bar) "*Il tient les murs*"

La grammaire est approximative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Gratter*** en langage familier veut dire « récupérer tout ce qui peut être utilisé », « gagner de petits profits » (Voir TLF, I, A, 5). Ici le verbe est employé de façon transitive : « gratter quelqu'un », construction peu habituelle, c'est à dire qu'il récupère tout de ce qu'il peut auprès des potos (argot pour potes - lui-même argotique !).

« Tenir les murs » veut dire passer son temps à ne rien faire, adossé au mur, comme si on était là pour l'empêcher de s'écrouler.  (Voir [sur Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/tenir-les-murs.php))

Comment: Pote vient de poteau, pas l'inverse.

Comment: @jlliagre Poteau a donné pote, je n'ai dit pas dit le contraire puisque je n'en parle pas. Mais il me semble que *poto* est un argot beaucoup plus récent et apparu après que le sens de poteau au sens d'amis ait été oublié.

Comment: La graphie "poto" (pour poteau) est récente, mais il me semble que l'argot "poteau" pour amis n'a pas vraiment cessé d'être utilisé. *L' jour de la fête à Julot, mon poteau*, 1954, Boris Vian.  Renaud l'a peut-être relancé en 1979: *Pierrot, 
mon gosse mon frangin, mon poteau,
mon copain, tu m'tiens chaud,
Pierrot.*

Answer (score 10):

C'est de l'argot.

*[Gratter](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/6837)* veut dire ici emprunter, prendre de l'argent (vivre aux dépens). La construction transitive « gratter quelqu'un » est courante.

*[Potos](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/3426)* est une graphie laxiste de *poteaux*, qui a donné le plus connu « [potes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pote) » voulant dire « amis ».

> Il emprunte de l'argent à ses amis.

Comment: Courante ? Je ne me rappelle pas avoir entendu « gratter quelqu'un », mais plutôt « gratter quelque chose » (comme « J'ai gratté un euro » ou « J'ai gratté une boîte de biscuits »).

Comment: @user285259 Oui, c'est juste mon opinion, forcément subjective. J'ai cependant déjà employé cette forme, et l'ai déjà entendue.